# How to add something to bash path without messing up existing bash commands?

Tags: macos

I'm doing some Android development and want to access the command line tools from anywhere.

There wasn't an existing .bash_profile file in my home directory so I created one and added the following line:

```
export PATH="/Users/Me/desktop/Android/Android SDK bundle/sdk/platform-tools"
```

I can now access the Android tools from terminal, however the ls command has stopped working, though cd still works. I get

```
-bash: ls: command not found
```

What should I do to get it to work again (and why has ls stopped working but cd still works?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
export PATH=$PATH:"/Users/Me/desktop/Android/Android SDK bundle/sdk/platform-tools"
```

It will append to the current `PATH` your sdk directory.

As for the later question, it stopped working because you overwritten your `PATH` variable, so bash can't find your binaries. However `cd`is a builtin command (http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_builtin.htm) it doesn't need a path to be located and executed.

Comment: Thanks. Now that previous bash commands aren't recognized I can't do something like "open -e .bash_profile" as open isn't recognized. Can I view the file in the finder?

Comment: Well that I don't know, but you can delete your ``.bash_profile`` by executing this on the terminal ``/bin/rm .bash_profile``on your home folder.